# How does taking the log of a variable to reduce its skewness change how we interpret that variable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normalization, skewness

I understand that taking the log of a variable is important to reduce the skewness of that variable, which thus allows it to be better suited for statistical tests such as OLS regression.

However, how should we interpret that variable after the log function has been applied to it?

Comment: You don’t need normal predictors to have the nice OLS properties like inference on the parameters. If a predictor follows an exponential distribution, so be it. For that matter, you don’t need a normal response variable. All that has to be normal is the error term. (There’s plenty that we can do if the error is not normal, but vanilla OLS inference does require that. Notably, however, the Gauss-Markov theorem does not require a normal error to get the minimum variance unbiased estimator of $\beta$.)

Comment: Correction: The G-M theorem does not state that OLS are MVUE under non-normality. It states that they are *MVLUE*, that is, minimum variance among the class of unbiased estimators that are *linear* functions of the Y data. Since there are so few estimators that are linear functions of the Y data (essentially non-existent outside of OLS and weighted OLS methods), the G-M theorem is practically worthless. In particular, ML estimates are generally better than OLS in terms of closeness to targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take the simple OLS regression model:
$$y_i=\beta_0 + \beta_{1}x_{i} + u_i$$
And transform it with the natural log:
$$\ln{y_i} = \beta_0 + \beta_{1}\ln{x_i} + u_i$$
Then we can interpret $\beta_1$ as the **percentage change** in $y_i$ associated with a **one percent change** in $x_i$.

---

edit: If we take the natural log of only $x_i$ such that we get the model:
$$y_i = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}\ln{x_i} + u_i$$
Then we would interpret $\beta_{1}$ here as a $\beta_{1}/100$ unit change in $y_i$ from a **one percent change** in $x_{i}$

You can consult [this page](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/10/learn-generalized-linear-models-glm-r.html/2) for a list of interpretations and log transformations of linear OLS models.

Comment: I think the point was that we don’t take the log $y_i$.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for pointing this out, I have updated it to reflect your comment